# text change on jquery :ischecked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a function to change the text on checkbox selection, please check following...

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('#active').is(':checked')) {
    $('strong', '#status').text('Active');
}
else {
    $('strong', '#status').text('Inactive');
}
});
```

Html Form

```
 <span id="status"><input name="active" type="checkbox" value="1" id="active" />
<strong>Active</strong></span>
```

It works perfect when page loads, but if we change value of #active or we click #active it doesn't change text like active or inactive. thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a doc ready block or just before the closing body tag you first need to attach a change handler to the element. You can then trigger the change event so that the text is correct when the page is rendered.

```
$(function(){

    function setDisplayText() {

      var displayText = this.checked ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';
      $('strong', '#status').text(displayText);

    }

    //setup change handler and then trigger 
    //it to ensure correct text on doc ready
    $('#active').change(setDisplayText)
                .trigger('change');

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach an event listener to your checkbox.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function updateStatus() {
    if($('#active').is(':checked')) {
      $('strong', '#status').text('Active');
    }
    else {
      $('strong', '#status').text('Inactive');
    }
  }

  $('#active').bind('change', updateStatus);

  updateStatus();

});
```

**Update** - changed code to fire on document ready as well.

Comment: yours code is working but doesn't work at first click, when i load page the checkbox is not ticked and it shows active instead of inactive.

Comment: this can also be done, by triggering the change event on load of the page. something like `$('#active').trigger('change');`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not binding the code to the onchange event of the checkbox.

When the page loads, your code just checks whether the checkbox is checked or not because the code is bound to the onready event of the document object. 
After this it will not run the same code again

You can try this.

```
$('#active').bind('change', function() {
    if($('#active').is(':checked')) {
     $('strong', '#status').text('Active');
    }
    else {
     $('strong', '#status').text('Inactive');
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired using the 'change' event handler?

It would look a little something like this:

```
$('#active').change(function(e)
{
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('strong', '#status').text('Active');
  }
  else {
    $('strong', '#status').text('Inactive');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function onChange of checkbox :

```
<input name="active" type="checkbox" value="1" id="active" onchange="ChangeText();"/>

$(document).ready(function() { 
function ChangeText() {
if($('#active').is(':checked')) {
     $('strong', '#status').text('Active');
 } else {
     $('strong', '#status').text('Inactive'); 
} 
}
});
```

you can call the same function (ChangeText) on onload of body.